# abi reported for Samsung Galaxy Tab S2

Tags: 6.0-marshmallow

When I run:

```
$adb shell getprop | grep abi
```

I get:

```
[ro.product.cpu.abi2]: [armeabi]
[ro.product.cpu.abi]: [armeabi-v7a]
[ro.product.cpu.abilist32]: [armeabi-v7a,armeabi]
[ro.product.cpu.abilist64]: []
[ro.product.cpu.abilist]: [armeabi-v7a,armeabi]
```

However according to http://www.phonearena.com/phones/Samsung-Galaxy-Tab-S2-9.7-inch_id9385 and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exynos I was expecting a ARMV8a architecture to be reported. For instance a Sony Z4 tablet reports as expected. What does for instance Nexus 6P report (I don't have that device).

Any idea why the Samsung device reports as it does?

The background to my question is that I'm planning to write an application with some C/Assembler code (using the NDK) and I would like to understand how many devices I can target if I go for the ARMv8 instruction set instead of ARMv7a.